# Perl regex single quote

Tags: regex, perl, shell

Can someome help me to run the command below. I also tried to escape the single quotes but no luck.

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/Object\.prototype\.myString='q'//' myfile.html
```

Answer (score 18):

The problem is not with Perl, but with your shell.  To see what's happening, try this:

```
$ echo 's/Object\.prototype\.myString='q'//'
s/Object\.prototype\.myString=q//
```

To make it work, you can replace each single quote with `'\''`, like this:

```
$ echo 's/Object\.prototype\.myString='\''q'\''//'
s/Object\.prototype\.myString='q'//
```

or you can save a few characters by writing just:

```
$ echo 's/Object\.prototype\.myString='\'q\''//'
s/Object\.prototype\.myString='q'//
```

or even just:

```
$ echo 's/Object\.prototype\.myString='\'q\'//
s/Object\.prototype\.myString='q'//
```

or even:

```
$ echo s/Object\\.prototype\\.myString=\'q\'//
s/Object\.prototype\.myString='q'//
```

Double quotes, as [suggested by mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948356/perl-regex-single-quote/7948426#7948426), will work here too, but can cause unwanted surprises in other situations, since many characters commonly found in Perl code, like `$`,  `!` and `\`, have special meaning to the shell even inside double quotes.

Of course, an alternative solution is to replace the single quotes in your regexp with the octal or hex codes `\047` or `\x27` instead:

```
$ perl -pi.bak -e 's/Object\.prototype\.myString=\x27q\x27//' myfile.html
```

Comment: In my case the recommendation for `\x27` seems the most simple and reliable -- worked great!

Answer (score 6):

Double quotes should work:

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s/Object\.prototype\.myString='q'//" myfile.html
```

You may or may not want a `g` modifier on that regex. And you'll probably want to do a `diff` after to make sure you didn't mangle the HTML.

Comment: This is what worked for me. I wanted to remove the quote and some other characters (spaces, parentheses, -, .) from the variable 'name' : prxchange("s/ |-|\.|\(|\)|\'//", -1, name)